# $injector:modulerr Failed to instantiate module bookApp due to: ReferenceError: 'when' is undefined at Anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am building an angularjs app which starts from a login page but when I execute my login page,i get below error in console.

[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module bookApp due to:
ReferenceError: 'when' is undefined
   at Anonymous function

PFB The relevant files.Any help is much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

P.S. Please let me know if any more information is required.

HTML :

```
<!doctype html>
<!--Mention the module name to <html> -->
<html ng-app="bookApp">
    <head>
        <title>Angular Assignment</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            @import "styles/style.css";

        </style>
        <script src="lib/Angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/Angular/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <!--include header.html -->
            <div ng-include="'Header.html'"></div>
        </center>
        <!-- Add the required controller to this div.
        Associate the models for username and password.-->
        <div  align="center" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
            <h2> Login </h2>
            <div class="LoginFormDiv">
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td> Username </td>
                        <td>:
                        <input ng-model="username" class="input" placeholder="Enter Username"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Password</td>
                        <td>:
                        <input ng-model="password" class="input" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                        <!-- On click of the button, call validate(user)  method declared in controller-->
                        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login" ng-click="validate()"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- include footer.html -->
        <center>
            <div ng-include="'Footer.html'"></div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller.js

```
var Controllers = angular.module('Controllers', ['ngRoute']);
Controllers.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', '$rootScope',
function($scope, $location, $http, $rootScope) {
    alert("I am in LoginCtrl")
    $scope.validate = function() {
        alert("I am in validate function");
        $http.get('data/roles.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.roles = data;
        });
        var count = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.roles, function(role) {
            if ($scope.username == role.username && $scope.password == role.password) {
                alert("login successful");
                count = count + 1;
                if ($scope.roles == "student") {
                    $location.path("/home/student");
                } else {
                    $location.path("/home/librarian");
                }
            } else if (count != 1) {
                alert("Please provide valid login credentials");
                $location.path("/main")
            }

        });
    }
}]);
```

app.js

```
var bookApp = angular.module('bookApp', ['Controllers', 'ngRoute']);
bookApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/main', {
        templateUrl : 'Login',
        controller : 'LoginCtrl'
    }).when('/home/student', {
        templateUrl : 'ViewBooks_Student.html',
        controller : 'BookListCtrl_Student'
    });
    when('/home/librarian', {
        templateUrl : 'ViewBooks_Librarian.html',
        controller : 'BookListCtrl_Librarian'
    });
    when('/issue/:bookId', {
        templateUrl : 'IssueBook.html',
        controller : 'IssueBookCtrl'
    });
    when('/return/:bookId', {
        templateUrl : 'ReturnBook.html',
        controller : 'ReturnBookCtrl'
    });
    otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/main'
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`routeProvider.when().when().when()` works.

`routeProvider.when();when();when()` doesn't. Semicolons matter.